# Trying to make app to make my FFOS phone mic/webcam for desktop

Tags: usb, webcam, microphone, firefox-os

I was doing research and couldn't get myself in the right direction so I figured I would ask if it's possible.

For my desktop computer I dont have a mic or a webcam but needed it for some applications.

So I thought to create an app for my Flame that when connected over USB will act as mic and webcam. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use webRTC to connect PC & phone and share webcam/mic (either phone->PC or PC->phone). Try `Firefox Hello` if you want to see how webRTC works.

For example, try http://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/ in both your device and desktop

Comment: Oh thanks so much! Is there any way you would be willing to make a simple demonstration app of this for me? This is my first app.

Comment: webrtc is a bit overskill for first app. try some other samples then back to webrtc will make more sense.

Comment: ok thanks ill try, reason i wanted this was because i needed a webcam/mic to talk with family for my desktop and i havent had the chance to go shopping for one (im not a fan of them i dont like how they look haha)